# Bootstrap 5 offcanvas disable close on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, off-canvas-menu

I'm using the offcanvas component (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/). However I was wondering if it is possible to prevent it from closing when I click outside the offcanvas window. I've managed to stop it from closing when I press ESC but theres no way (as far as the docs go) to prevent it from closing when I do a mouse click outside of the offcanvas. Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT:
I managed to get it working halfway by listening for the hide.bs.offcanvas event and then using e.preventDefault(); However now I'm unable to close the offcanvas with its default close button because it will always cancel the hide event. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap adds a click listener to the `body`. Therefore, you would attach a click event listener to the `body`, and stop the event from propagating...

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/qd4RPKwCNF)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to work, is this fine to use though? Won't this cause other events/document click listeners to not behave properly? Just wondering

Comment: It would only impact listeners attached to the body (which the developer should be aware of!). As you can see from the demo it doesn't cause issues with the other Bootstrap events.. and it's the only way to address the question you asked.

Comment: i try this solution but is the dropdown is affected and not close when its open

Comment: @francojohnc Hi, try updating your bootstrap, in newer versions the offcanvas does not close anymore when you click on other parts of the page

Comment: @sharpness: I'm using BS 5.1.3 and can confirm that a standard offcanvas does close when you click the backdrop.

Comment: @Zim: In version 5.1.1, this no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

Now, adding `data-bs-backdrop="static"` prevents offcanvas to close when clicking outside of it (= clicking on backdrop)

Reference https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/#static-backdrop

Comment: this is the solution. actually

Answer (score 1):

I found a CSS only solution for this by setting `pointer-events:none` on the `offcanvas-backdrop` class. The exact CSS style would be

```
.offcanvas-backdrop.fade.show {
 pointer-events:none 
}
```

This will prevent any click events on the offcanvas' backdrop and click events inside the offcanvas will work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `data-bs-keyboard="false"` as a data-attribute of the off-canvas element seems to work in Bootsrap 5.1.1

Comment: It does work at least in Boostrap 5.2.3, which allows keeping the offcanvas opened without a backdrop:
data-bs-scroll="true" data-bs-backdrop="false" data-bs-keyboard="false"

Answer (score 0):

By using beforeDismiss return false, it won't close on dismiss option, since click on backdrop is pointed to dismiss it won't close the offcanvas, in order close the offcanvas we can use close method

```
ngbCanvasOptions: NgbOffcanvasOptions = {
    beforeDismiss: () => {
      return false;
    },
    keyboard: false,
    animation: true
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.offcanvas-backdrop {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

will work as expected

place it on the root CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

The **Bootstrap 5.2** introduces new options to do it.
The feature is [**Static backdrop**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/#static-backdrop)

But the **Bootstrap 5.1** haven't it.
But you can use js code:

```js
let offcanvasEl = $("#myOffcanvas");
let offcanvasAllowClose = false;

offcanvasEl.find("button, a").on("click", () => offcanvasAllowClose = true);

offcanvasEl.on("hide.bs.offcanvas", (ev) => {
    if (offcanvasAllowClose) return;
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't love this solution, but it works for my needs as of today. (I'm really hoping Bootstrap will give us this functionality ASAP.)

```js
$("#myOffcanvas").on("shown.bs.offcanvas", function () {
    const backdrop = $(".offcanvas-backdrop");
    const parent = backdrop.parent();
    const cloned = backdrop.clone();
    backdrop.remove();
    parent.append(cloned);
}).on("hide.bs.offcanvas", function () {
    $(".offcanvas-backdrop").remove();
});
```